# Handling the NULL data in impala

Tags: sql, hive, null, impala

I am trying understand the behavior of arithmetic operation in impala

i am using the following table

```
╔════╦══════════════╦══════════╗
║ id ║  name        ║ salary   ║
╠════╬══════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║  cde         ║ 5636     ║
║  2 ║  asd         ║  148     ║
║  3 ║  pwe         ║  null    ║
║  4 ║  lmn         ║  959     ║
╚════╩══════════════╩══════════╝
```

when i execute the following query

```
select salary+20 as sum1 from table where id=3;
```

it returns me

```
     |sum1
  ---|-----
   1 |NULL
```

when i run sum on the column with

```
select sum(salary) as sum1 from table;

     |sum1
  ---|-----
   1 |6743
```

I am unable to understand how same arithmetic operations are behaving differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
select sum(COALESCE(salary,0)) as sum1 from table;
```

This should ensure that the value returned is a number. Similar to leftjoin's answer. You could also do this with case statements or where statements.

Source:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/impala_conditional_functions.html

Answer (score 1):

NULL is not a zero (0) and zero is not a NULL, it's a value, and this is most important. NULL is absence of the value, nothing. `sum()` aggregates values only. If it were no any values in the dataset then it returns NULL. If it were some values, sum() will aggregate them, ignoring nulls. If you want to convert `NULL` it to zero, use `NVL()` function:

```
select nvl(sum(salary),0) as sum1 from table where ...
```

This query will return 0 in case there are no values in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

These are different arithmetic queries.

In your first query you want the DB to return `salary+20` from row 3. Well the `salary` of row 3 is `NULL`. So the DB will see that `NULL+20=NULL` and return `NULL`.

However in the second query: `sum(salary) from table;` is asking the DB to sum the entire `salary` column and return it to you. So it looks at it and does `5636+148+959=6743` (ignores `NULL`).

In conclusion in the first query you are executing a basic arithmetic operator. But the second query `sum()` is an operator that is applied to returned rows. As a better test, try running `select sum(salary) as sum1 from table where id=3` and see what you get to better understand what is happening.

Comment: according to your theory when i do sum(salary) from table where id=3 should ignore null and print sum as zero.But still it is returning NULL

Comment: Ah I see where you might be confused. So in `sum()` if there are valid values in the DB it'll return the sum of those valid values. But if you are trying to sum invalid values ie. `a+null+1.144es` or something it'll complain and return `null`. But `10+null+20+a` will return `30`.

Comment: 10+null+20+a is also returning NULL

Comment: Maybe I'm a little off then on this particular DBMS? Then `null` must just be treated as a special case in this sense and is conditionally ignored. So `10+20+null+null` should be `30`.